# mysql Error 2002  - unable to connect to local mysql server 

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I tried connect to mysql locally. after
 `using mysql --username='*****' --password='*****'`
A message displayed like:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

I went to /var/run/mysqld/mysqkd.sock
It was an empty file!
what is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

MySQL is not running. Check logs, process lists (ps aux) etc. Do some homework.